# Laravel Model get's wrong ID after saving

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1

I've got a Laravel application (5.1.28) which I have running on a development server and production server.

dev:
php 5.6.13
mysql 5.6.19

prod:
php 5.6.16
mysql 5.5.27

mysql table:

`CREATE TABLE testquestions (
  id bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  testquestiongroup_id bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  description varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  type varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  created_at timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  updated_at timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;`

And the following php code;

`$question = new Question();
$question->testquestiongroup_id = $questiongroup->id;
$question->save();`

The code on my dev and prod environment are the same. Als the database content are the same, copied from prod to dev.

When I run this code my $question object will get a wrong ID back from mysql(?). When I check MySQL there is a new record with a (good) ID, but this ID isn't returned to my object. It get the same wrong ID over and over again. The wrong ID is from an object added 4 months ago.

This problem doesn't occur on my dev environment.

Is there some bug in MySQL or am I doing something wrong? Thanks

**UPDATE 12febr**

The problem get keeping weirder!
I tried the following code after inserting my code ($question->save())

`var_dump($question);
var_dump(\DB::getPdo()->lastInsertId());`

My question object gives a different ID ($question->id) than \DB::getPdo()->lastInsertId(). The returned ID from the $question object stays the wrong ID. The lastInsertId function returns the right ID!

Does it matter that the field is a BIGINT(20) ?

Comment: Please recheck your database credentials  in the remote `.env` file.

Comment: The connection with the database is no problem. The app writes to the right database, but gives back a wrong ID to my model object.

Comment: Any solution?? I have the same problem with laravel 5.2

Answer (score 3):

I have some similar problem and finally solved it. Not the same, but it is also about *laravel-model-gets-wrong-id-after-saving*, so I hope I can post it here to let someone having my problem solve it.

My solution: Check about the `DB::getPdo()->lastInsertId()`. If it is also wrong, then check whether you have some sql insert statement inside `DB::listen` callback.

I am a fool for I tried to log my sql statement inside DB::listen by using an `insert` statement. This is the problem.

Comment: Exactly! How to get around this?

Comment: @SergeyRomanov For my case (3 years ago), we give up logging sql statement into a database. Actually, using a log file or something else may be better.

Comment: I see. I was thinking to save a log as a static array and write those on app close. But actually files might be an even better options. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I had some problems with id's in laravel/eloquent.

Setting the incrementing variable to false in the specific model helped me most of the time.

Perhaps this will help you too.